# Random Forest uses only 2/3rd of the training set to generate individual tree

Tags: r, weka

I am using Random Forest in my Project. I want to use all the training set samples with replacement for creating individual random trees and not just 2/3rd of the training set and leaving the 1/3rd for OOB error calculation. 
How can I do this in Weka or R?

In short, making sure Random forest uses all training samples to generate individual trees and not just 2/3rd of the training set.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's really leaving 1/3 observations aside?  This does not sound like any standard random forest implementation with which I'm familiar.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I don't know about R/Weka, but original Breiman's RF chose a different 2/3 of the trainining set *for each tree*, with 1/3 for cross-validation. This means that all instances were used, you just needed to make a big enough forest. The whole point of RF was that each tree is relatively stupid (to prevent overfitting), but the forest is smart.

Comment: Oh...I thought he meant that 2/3 is used for the entire building of the tree, and then 1/3 is leftover at the end.  What you describe is what I recall...I don't think the OP should really be changing this much.

Comment: Well the theory says, for creating each individual tree it uses 2/3rd of the training set. So the samples are chosen with replacement after each tree, but still it uses only 2/3rd, but I want it to use all the samples to generate trees, as I have a separate test set with me, instead of the random forest's 1/3rd left out set. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really. Let me state it again: "The whole point of RF was that each tree is relatively stupid (to prevent overfitting), but the forest is smart.". The purpose of withholding 1/3 of data from each tree is not just so you can crossvalidate. If you use your whole dataset for each tree, you *will* overfit; unless you have a very good reason, you shouldn't do it.

Comment: @Amadan: Thank you for this good explanation. I found the solution in R and not in Weka. Thank you for that good point.